# How can I cut down the complexity of O(n^3) ? (Code is provided)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I'm writing this method to find the number of common numbers in 3 arrays (duplicates are allowed, e.g. `if A=[1,3,3,3,6], B=[3,3,1,5], C=[3,3,1,5,2]` then method should return 3; two 3's + one 1). I used 3 for loops, but I feel like there should be a better way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
private static int common(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C)
{
    int c=0;
    List<Integer> visitedBs=new ArrayList<Integer>(), visitedCs=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        outerloop:
        for (int j = 0; j <B.length ; j++)
            if (A[i]==B[j] && !visitedBs.contains(j))
                for (int k = 0; k < C.length; k++)
                    if (B[j] == C[k] && !visitedCs.contains(k)) {
                        c++;
                        visitedBs.add(j);
                        visitedCs.add(k);
                        break outerloop;
                    }

    return c;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I should cut down the time complexity? is there a way to use 2 for loops instead?

Comment: Is this really cubic time, and not a 4th power, thanks to the linear search through `visitedCs`?

Comment: You can do it in O(n log n). First sort each array, then use one loop with three indexes in those arrays that only increment. A comment is too short for giving an algorithm. You might find it out yourself.

Comment: @harold Interesting! I didn't take that into considerations. I think it could be a 4th power. Is there a way to avoid using '''visitedCs'''?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think that could work. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Does Java have anything resembling Python's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)? That would give you a linear time solution. (Essentially, `sum((Counter(A) & Counter(B) & Counter(C)).values())`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm kind of a beginner, so I honestly wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the complexity is even worse as contains() also does a for loop.

You can create 3 collections that contain the content of A, B and C, I call them X_remaining. For every element in A_remaining, check if it's contained in B_remaining and C_remaining. If so, increment c and erase the found elements in all collections. Try to reuse the search result to not search again when removing.

To find elements faster than linear you can use TreeSet. Maybe HashSet is also an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, to achieve `O(n^2)` complexity for this task:

```
private static int common(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) { 
  List<Integer> listA = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  List<Integer> listB = Arrays.stream(B).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  List<Integer> listC = Arrays.stream(C).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

  listA.retainAll(listB);
  listA.retainAll(listC);

  listB.retainAll(listA);
  listB.retainAll(listC);

  listC.retainAll(listA);
  listC.retainAll(listB);

  return Math.min(listA.size(), Math.min(listB.size(), listC.size()));
}
```

Also, IMO you can get `O(n)` solution, for example:

```
private static long common(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
  Map<Integer, Long> frequencyA = findFrequencies(A);
  Map<Integer, Long> frequencyB = findFrequencies(B);
  Map<Integer, Long> frequencyC = findFrequencies(C);

  Set<Integer> common = frequencyA.keySet();
  common.retainAll(frequencyB.keySet());
  common.retainAll(frequencyC.keySet());

  return frequencyA.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> common.contains(e.getKey()))
    .mapToLong(e -> Math.min(e.getValue(), Math.min(frequencyB.get(e.getKey()), frequencyC.get(e.getKey()))))
    .sum();
}

private static Map<Integer, Long> findFrequencies(int[] A) {
  return Arrays.stream(A)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert each array into a Map mapping each number that occurs into the count of occurrences for that number (`map.compute( (key,prev) -> (prev==null ? 1 : prev+1) )`).  This takes O(N)

Compute the minimum count for each key across all maps.  Also O(N)

Add all up all the minimum counts to get the answer.  Also O(N).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` here, that for each sublist counts the number of times it is present in the sublist. A simple Haskell program looks like:

```
import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
import Data.HashMap.Strict(HashMap, alter, elems, empty, intersectionWith)
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

toCounter :: (Eq a, Hashable a, Integral i) => [a] -> HashMap a i
toCounter = foldr (alter (Just . maybe 1 (1+))) empty

mergeCount :: (Eq a, Hashable a, Integral i) => HashMap a i -> HashMap a i -> HashMap a i
mergeCount = intersectionWith min
```

Then we can calculate the result with:

```
calculateMinOverlap :: (Eq a, Hashable a, Integral i, Functor f, Foldable f) => f [a] -> i
calculateMinOverlap = sum . elems . foldr1 mergeCount . fmap toCounter
```

We can then calculate the minimum overlap with:

```
Main> calculateMinOverlap [[1,3,3,3,6], [3,3,1,5], [3,3,1,5,2]]
3
```

It takes linear time in total number of elements, and the function can process an arbitrary number of sublists (given there is at least one sublist).

The `toCounter` takes linear time in the size of the sublist *O(m)*. When we perform an `fmap toCounter`, we will thus process all the lists in *O(n)*, with *n* the total number of elements.

Next the `mergeCount` works in *O(m<sub>1</sub>+m<sub>2</sub>)* with *m<sub>1</sub>* and *m<sub>2</sub>* the number of elements in the two `HashMap`s respectively. It will each time return a `HashMap` that contains a number of elements that is at most the smallest of the two. This thus means that our `foldr1 mergeCount` works in *O(n)* as well.

Finally we retrieve the `elems` of the result in *O(m)* with *m* the number of elements in the final `HashMap`, and `sum` takes *O(m)* as well.

Note that strictly speaking for huge numbers, the minimum of two arbitrary large numbers, etc. takes *O(log v)* with *v* the value of that number. The same holds for incrementing, etc. So if the number of objects is huge, it can, strictly speaking, scale with *O(n* log *n)*.